# Need help getting private attributes from another class when using Arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, element, private

I'm a fairly new programmer and I have a problem.

Im making a dog register, which has to have at least two classes (one for the dogs and one for the actual program) and the attributes for the dogs have to be private. The dog register also have to use an arraylist to store the dogs information and to add/remove dogs and so on.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to get the dogs attributes to be listen correctly when I want to show all the elements of the list to the user.

This is (scaled down) what it looks like now:

```
  public class Dog {

        private String name;
        public Hund(String name) {
        this.name = name; 
        }

        public String getName() {
        return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
        setName(name);
        }

        public void writeOut() {
        System.out.print(getName())
        }
```

And then there's this class: The main program

```
        import java.util.ArrayList;

        public class DogRegister {

        private static ArrayList<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<Dog>();

        //The part with the program and menus and such

        for(int ix = 0; ix < dogs.size(); ix++){    
            String elementName = dogs.get(ix);
            elementName.writeOut();

            } 
        }
```

What Im trying to do in the last part is to use the "writeOut" method so that the actual name (and other attributes) for the dogs is being written out instead of the "Dog@2ad1e832" I got when I tested it with:

```
System.out.println(dogs.get(ix));
```

Comment: dogs.get(ix); should return a Dog, not a String. Keep the same code except this line: Dog dog = dogs.get(ix); and it'll work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [override the toString() method](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-tostring-method-in-java/) to display how the `Dog` object should look:

```
    @Override  
    public String toString()
    {
        return name + "," + breed; // You can add other attributes here as well.
    }
```

Just place the `toString()` method in your `Dog` class and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, try replacing your `for` loop with this:

```
for (Dog dog : dogs) {
  System.out.println(dog.getName())
}
```

Or if you wanted to use the same structure of your original loop, try this:

```
for (int ix=0; ix < dogs.size(); ix++) {
  Dog dog = dogs.get(ix);
  System.out.println(dog.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to override `toString` method in the `Dog` class to change the output of `System.out.println(dogs.get(ix));`
For example:

```
public class Dog {
    ...

    @Override 
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `dogs.get(ix).getName()`.You are trying to print object.